# Returning the maximum date in the inner join table

Tags: sql-server

I have a order and order_items table:

```
Order
-id

Items
-id
-order_id
-date_added
-price
```

In addition to what I have below, I want to return the MAX date_added value as a column for item.  How can I do that?

```
select item.id, count(*)
from orders o
    inner join items i on o.id = i.order_id
group by item.id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [MAX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) function

```
select item.id, count(*), MAX(date_added)
from orders o
    inner join items i on o.id = i.order_id
group by item.id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple query should do it for you:

```
select item.id, count(*) count_of_orders, max(date_added ) max_date_added
from orders o
    inner join items i on o.id = i.order_id
group by item.id
order by count(*) desc
```